# weird characters being displayed after publish

Tags: html

Here's my url http://bloomh.com/

If you look down in the "testimonial" section you'll see a bunch of weird characters being displayed. Strange thing is that it seems to "grow" over time and the code is inside my html. Obviously I did not add this to my original html.

How and why is this happening. Very strange. Any help and direction would be greatly appreciated.

Ok here's the html and php. The weird characters are inside the html however I did not add that at all. Also another small caveat is I used the frontend creator Webflow.com and then exported the html and transferred over to my hosting. Webflow is pretty legit and I've already spoken with them and they've assured me that their code is clean. Once again this happened after I published the page and used the php form a couple of times then those weird characters started to "grow" over time.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- This site was created in Webflow. http://www.webflow.com-->
<!-- Last Published: Tue Aug 19 2014 18:12:20 GMT+0000 (UTC) -->
<html data-wf-site="5359ea800548c9ed4700023a" data-wf-page="53dbf829e673629c186afc3f">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bloomh</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="generator" content="Webflow">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/webflow.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bloomhmvp.webflow.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js"></script>
  <script>
    WebFont.load({
      google: {
        families: ["Carme:regular","Roboto Slab:300,regular,700","Nixie One:regular","Pontano Sans:regular","Quicksand:300,regular,700","Muli:300,300italic,regular,italic","Raleway:300,regular,500,600,700,800,900","Arimo:regular,italic,700,700italic","Oxygen:300,regular,700","Cabin:regular,italic,500,500italic,600,600italic,700,700italic","Roboto:300,300italic,regular,italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic"]
      }
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/fontawesome-webfont.svg">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="w-nav navbar vl" data-collapse="medium" data-animation="default" data-duration="400">
    <div class="w-clearfix navbar-section">
      <div class="logo-container vl">
        <a class="w-nav-brand logo vl" href="#"></a><a class="brand vl" href="#">Bloomh</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hero-background home2 vl">
    <div class="w-container hero-container">
      <div class="coming-soon">COMING SOON!</div>
      <div class="centering-container _95">
        <h1 class="hero-tagline home2 vendor-landing vl">Brides set the price<br>Vendors come to them</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="centering-container _85 tablet">
        <h2 class="secondary-tagline home2 vendor-landing vl">A new way to hire&nbsp;photographers &amp; videographers</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="vendor-question-box">
        <div class="w-row">
          <div class="w-col w-col-4">
            <div class="w-form">
              <form id="wf-form-vl2-signup" action="php/vl2_submit.php" method="post" name="wf-form-vl2-signup" data-name="vl2 signup" data-redirect="http://www.bloomh.com">
                <div class="centering-container">
                  <input class="w-input post-page-input-fields input-fields vendor-landing vl" id="vl2-email" type="email" placeholder="Valid Email" name="vl2_email" data-name="vl2 email" required="required">
                  <input class="w-input post-page-input-fields input-fields vendor-landing vl" id="vl2-address" type="text" placeholder="Website address?" name="vl2_address" data-name="vl2 address" required="required">
                  <input class="w-button button join-button vendor-join vl" type="submit" value="Vendor Join!" data-wait="Joining..." wait="Joining...">
                </div>
              </form>
              <div class="w-form-done">
                <p>Thank you! Your submission has been received!</p>
              </div>
              <div class="w-form-fail">
                <p>Oops! Something went wrong while submitting the form :(</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="w-col w-col-8">
            <div class="centering-container _85 vl">
              <div class="vendor-question vl">Are you a Photographer or Videographer?</div>
              <div class="w-hidden-main w-hidden-medium w-hidden-small how-to-wrap vl">
                <div class="centering-container vendor-sale mobile">
                  <div class="vendor-sale-text vl">Sign Up</div>
                </div>
                <div class="centering-container">
                  <div class="fa fa-chevron-down vendor-welcome vl"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="centering-container mobile">
                  <div class="vendor-sale-text vl get-clients">Get clients via email</div>
                </div>
                <div class="centering-container">
                  <div class="fa fa-chevron-down mobile"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="centering-container mobile">
                  <div class="vendor-sale-text vl">Free and Easy!</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="w-hidden-tiny vendor-question-subtext phone">
                <div class="vendor-how-to vendor-landing vl">Sign Up</div>
                <div class="fa fa-chevron-right vendor-landing vl"></div>
                <div class="vendor-how-to vendor-landing vl">Get clients in your inbox</div>
                <div class="fa fa-chevron-right vendor-landing vl"></div>
                <div class="vendor-how-to vendor-landing vl">Free and Easy!</div>
              </div>
              <div class="more-categories vendor-landing vl">Birthdays / Portraits / Parties / Bat Mitzvahs / Engagements</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="vl-testimonials">
    <div class="centering-container vl testimonials">
      <div class="testimonial vl">Testimonials</div>
      <div class="testimonial-text vl">ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€ Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Â ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã¢â€žÂ¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€ Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¬ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Â¦Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¬ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€ Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ã‚Â¬Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¦ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¬ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Â¦ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…â€œI use Bloomh to get most of my new wedding clients. It plays a big part in growing my business.ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€ Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Â ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã¢â€žÂ¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€ Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¬ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Â¦Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¬ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€ Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ã‚Â¬Ãƒâ€¦Ã‚Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â</div>
      <div class="testimonial-user main vl">- Lance Capshaw, Huntington Beach CA
        <br>(Vendor)</div>
      <div class="testimonial-text vl">ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€ Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Â ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã¢â€žÂ¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€ Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¬ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Â¦Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¬ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€ Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ã‚Â¬Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¦ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¬ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Â¦ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…â€œI can't believe this service is free! I&nbsp;use it to get my wedding clients. They just come into my inbox!ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€ Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Â ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã¢â€žÂ¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€ Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¬ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Â¦Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â¬ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™Ãƒâ€ Ã¢â‚¬â„¢ÃƒÆ’Ã‚Â¢ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ã‚Â¬Ãƒâ€¦Ã‚Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã†â€™ÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã…Â¡ÃƒÆ’Ã¢â‚¬Å¡Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â</div>
      <div class="testimonial-user main vl">- Trish Carpenter, Hermosa Beach, CA
        <br>(Vendor)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/webflow.js"></script>
  <!--[if lte IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/placeholders/3.0.2/placeholders.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
</body>
</html>

**** PHP  ****
<?php
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['vl2_email']);
$website_address = htmlspecialchars($_POST['vl2_address']);
mail("bpark@bloomh.com", "New Vendor vl2", "From: $email", "Website Address: $website_address");
header("Location:../vl2-confirm.html");
?>
```

Comment: post code of where you are getting the testimonial content from...?

Comment: It's in the source code. Are you using any server-side language?

Comment: Source issue. Post your code please.

Comment: It looks to me like you're not properly saving/fetching this data in proper Unicode format. What do you mean it grows over time? How much time?

Comment: I agree it's probably missing a proper unicode tag OR you were a victim of copy and paste which I recommend retyping or copying the text into a text only program then pasting it into your HTML.

Comment: thank you guys. I just updated my initial post above. Would appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 0):

1) Search the whole code with the class name "testimonial-text" and see the code, try to replace the content after typing from notepad.

2) add a `<p>Your content content</p>` for your paragraphs.

3) you can paste the server side code for us.

4) You need to tell to MySQL that the connection must be made in UTF-8.

Comment: thank you. I just updated my initial post. Would appreciate your further insight